# Remove Mask from Image OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I may be overshooting a bit but **I'm trying to use a mask generated from my image and subtract it from the main image**. I'm quite open to instead extracting the characters but am not sure how to collect the entire blue sample, I haven't that correct balance yet.

The [page here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062216/replace-mask-with-original-image-opencv-python) demonstrates the inverse of what I'm trying to achieve.

**Base image**

[image]

**The mask utilizing hsv bounds then inverting it to show it better**

[image]

**Darkening it**

[image]

I wish to now take that mask and remove it from the main image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random as rng

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps
from utils import helper

image_name = 'capt13.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(image_name)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_red = np.array([0,120,70]) 
upper_red = np.array([10,255,255]) 
lower_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) 

lower_red = np.array([160,120,70]) 
upper_red = np.array([180,255,255]) 
upper_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) 
'''
lower_blue = np.array([80,40,30]) 
upper_blue = np.array([140,255,255]) 
lower_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue) 

lower_blue = np.array([240,220,200]) 
upper_blue = np.array([360,255,255]) 
upper_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue) 
'''
mask = lower_mask + upper_mask

res_lines = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask) 

# Keep the inverted
image = Image.fromarray(res_lines)
image.save('res.png')
inverted = ImageOps.invert(image)
inverted = inverted.convert('L')
inverted.save('inverted.png')

binary = np.array(inverted)
for row in range(len(binary)):
    for col in range(len(binary[row])):
        if binary[row][col] != 255:
            binary[row][col] = 0
binary_image = Image.fromarray(binary)
binary_image.save('binary.png')
```

Extracting the Blue (As stated above that I'm open to a better solution for this)

**The mask utilizing hsv bounds then inverted it**

[image]

**Darkening it**

[image]

Comment: OK, so what's the question/problem?

Comment: "I'm trying to use a mask generated from my image and subtract it from the main image."

Answer (score 2):

Straight subtraction works, provided both images are the same size:

```
im = cv2.imread("image.png")
mask = cv2.imread("mask.png")

diff_im = im - im2
```

Alternatively, you can use OpenCV's built in subtract, which does an element-wise subtraction:

```
diff_im = cv2.subtract(im, im2)
```

As a final thought, you should also try `absdiff`, as it will convert negative results to zeroes, which may be what you want.

```
diff_im = cv2.absdiff(im, im2)
```